# Express 4+pug disable layout

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to ajax for blocks that without layout
Such as

```
extends layout
block content
  p xxxx
```

I want to get the content in block

```
if !layout
  include layout
```

The solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the standard pug layout then create a file that doesn't have `extends layout` in it:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en-us')
  head
    title Page Title
  body
    div Content goes here
```

You don't need to do anything in your app.js file to make this happen.  You've probably figured out that none of the statements in your question work.  This is all controlled in the pug template file.

Comment: But I want to disable it when sth is true. It seems that I cant `if` before `extends`

Comment: Correct, `extends` is not applicable inside an if.  However, `include` can be.  You should consider editing your question to make it more clear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Okkk. Sry for my fault. Ty alot!!